# Python win32COM - COM Error: Member not found. (0x-7ffdfffd)

Tags: python, excel, win32com, alm

I am working on a Python script which opens an excel using win32com and make modification to it.

I am facing an issue while calling `objNewRange=objWrkBook.Worksheets('Sheet1').Range('$A$2:$T$15')`.

I am getting the error :

```
Run-time error -2147352573: Member not found.
```

The script works fine when I run it from python shell, but I am calling the same code from  HP ALM. I am able to write specifically to a cell using 'Cells' method but it looks like Python is unable to find the Range method.

Below is the Code fragment

```
# Newin [PythonScript]
# Created by Application Lifecycle Management
# 7/7/2016 4:06:15 PM
# ====================================================
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import xlsxwriter
import string
import os
import shutil
import pythoncom
import sys
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime
import imp
import argparse
import glob
import re
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse, tostring
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et




# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# StrVerifyExpResults Function:
# Description: This is the main fucntion that is used to compare the expected values to the actual ones. This calls in subfucntions to perform different operations
# Debug - Boolean. Equals to false if running in [Test Mode] : reporting to Application Lifecycle Management
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def StrVerifyExpResults(strFileName, strFilePath, strCurrentTestCaseID, intRowNum):
    '''Opening the Input sheet'''

    #strFileOpenStatus ='Success'


    strFileOpenStatus, objWrkBook=OpenInputSheet(strFileName, strFilePath)    
    if strFileOpenStatus=='Success':

        '''Get all row numbers from the input sheet'''
        objWrkSheet=objWrkBook.Worksheets('Sheet1')        
        objDataRange=GetUsedRowRange(objWrkBook, 'Sheet1')


        #Getting Range where the Data Is available       
        objNewRange=objWrkBook.Worksheets('Sheet1').Range('$A$2:$T$15')
        print objNewRange.Address



# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Function:
# Description: This is the main fucntion that is used to compare the expected values to the actual ones. This calls in subfucntions to perform different operations
# Debug - Boolean. Equals to false if running in [Test Mode] : reporting to Application Lifecycle Management
# CurrentTestSet - [OTA COM Library].TestSet.
# CurrentTSTest - [OTA COM Library].TSTest.
# CurrentRun - [OTA COM Library].Run.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def Test_Main(Debug, CurrentTestSet, CurrentTSTest, CurrentRun):
    try:

        # clear output window
        TDOutput.Clear()
        # TODO: put your code here        
        status=StrVerifyExpResults('input.xlsx','D:\\GVOL\\01 - Docs\\Automation\\WS Automation\\Input Sheet\\','1',2)        
    except pythoncom.com_error, (hr, desc, exc, arg):
           TDOutput.Print("Run-time error %d: %s" % (hr, desc))




def OpenInputSheet(strFileName2, strFilePath2):

    #excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')    
    excel.Visible = False

    wb = win32.GetObject(strFilePath2 + strFileName2)
    ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
    return ('Success', wb)
```

Comment: If scripts works, then the problem is *HP ALM*. Check its environment, settings, properties. Check if full fledged Python is installed with third-party modules like `win32com`?

Comment: I did check the installation of Python. HP ALM use the same Python Interpreter to execute. Also, it was able to find other methods like 'Worksheet.Cells(1,1).Value' which makes me think that its is getting confused about 'worksheet.Range("1:1")'